# Cannot get sort function to work correctly in JTable in Java application

Tags: java, jtable, tablerowsorter

I'm trying to get integer values to sort correctly in a JTable.

##### Currently, the output looks like this:

```
99
989
983
98
```

##### However, I expect the output to be:

```
989
983
99
98
```

##### Here is an image of my JTable:

[image: JTable image]

##### Here is my code:

```
private void populateTable(String[][] dataArray, String[] columnNames) {
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(dataArray, columnNames) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    return Object.class;
                } else {
                    return Integer.class;
                }
            }

        };

        tableStatistics.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        tableStatistics.setModel(tableModel);

        System.out.println(tableStatistics.getColumnClass(2));

    }
```

I have looked at forums and people say that overriding `getCustomClass` to specify column data type will solve the problem, however it has not.

I want the integer values to be sorted correctly.

I can confirm the `getColumnClass` override has successfully changed the data format but the sort still doesn't work.

##### Question

How do I go about getting the JTable to be able to sort this way?

Comment: Please provide the code as ```code``` instead of an image.

Comment: Could you incorporate a clear and explicit question?